# Laravel dynamic singleton binding can't resolve by Queue Worker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

In my Laravel application, I've to make third-party API call so I'm storing all details related third-party in Database ( URL and password, etc. ). To make this  Client available to everywhere in the application I've created Service Provider

**ServiceProvider.php**

```php
 $thirdParties = ThirdParty::all();

 collect($thirdParties)->each(function ($thirdParty) {
            $this->app->singleton(Str::snake($thirdParty->name), function ($app) use($thirdParty) {
                $config = new Config();
                $config->setLoginUrl($thirdParty->auth_url)
                    ->setUsername($thirdParty->username)
                    ->setPassword($thirdParty->password);
                $client = new Client($config);
                $client->Login();
                return $client;
            });
        });
```

Everything working file as provider fetches all Thrid Patry and register singleton class. The application user can also add new Third Party from UI so now to make that singleton I've put the same code with single `$thirdParty`.

**Problem**

So when new Third Party get added application will dispatch a Job where I utilize the same Singleton instance of the same class. But due to dynamic binding in Laravel Container, my job worker didn't know how to resolve that and starting to fail.

PS: After restarting Queue worker everything seems working fine.

Any help or alternative ways are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Clemen, the queue worker is a long-lived process, it's a PHP instance, and the application is already bootstrapped when you deployed the application.

I would suggest you run `Artisan::call('queue:restart')` each time your ThirdParty create, update and delete. You can achieve this by using [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events) or just manually doing it in your APIs(Controller).

The problem exists when you update them too, it's because the API's credentials would remain stale, so you have to do it on create, update and delete.

Example:

```
class ThirdParty extends Model
{

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function (ThirdParty $thirdParty) {
            Artisan::call('queue:restart');
        });
        static::updating(function (ThirdParty $thirdParty) {
            Artisan::call('queue:restart');
        });
        static::deleted(function (ThirdParty $thirdParty) {
            Artisan::call('queue:restart');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your Queue worker, it is running always in background (if you have a monitor process like Supervisor), so it register the singletons the first time, if you add more Third-parties after that, it will not load anything more. For that reason when you restart queue worker it start works.

You can see this advice in Laravel documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

> Remember, queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

I hope it helps you.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. can you suggest me an alternative way to fix this?

Comment: The way is actually simple when user add a new Thirdparty, you have to restart your queue worker.

Comment: One option is to restart the queue worker each time the user add a new Thirdparty \Artisan::call('queue:restart'); but it take a time it's not immediately. But  I think that the best solution is dispatch the Job including information about this Thirdparty, and then when the worker get the job, it must have the responsibility of create this new singleton before use it.

Comment: The user upload classes (files)? or all of this kind of classes are stored before in the application? If the classes are not include in the class loading process, the unique solution is restart the worker.